# Is Hachnasat Orchim among the 613 Mitzvot listed by Rambam or Chinuch?

Tags: mitzvah, hachnasat-orchim-guests

Is welcoming guests among the Mitzvot listed in these sfarim (Sefer HaMitzvot, Sefer HaChinuch)?

Comment: Rambam writes it's a rabbinic command (Avel 14:1-2) so I wouldn't expect to find it mentioned in the two books your mention. But someone would have to check to make sure

Comment: I just looked that up. Thank you and very interesting. So the Mishna in Peah (1:1) is talking all about rabbinic decrees?

Comment: As far as I remember the Rambam says that the mishna in Peah provides examples of the *de'oraysah* of *ve'ahavta le'reachah komochah*. So the *klal* is *de'oraysah* but the *halachos peratiyos* are *de'rabannan*.